# Does iOS 11 have an API for handwriting recognition and text search?

Tags: ios, ios11, handwriting-recognition

Apple has added searchable handwriting to the Notes app in iOS 11 ([iOS 11 Preview link](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-11-preview/)). This allows you to write on the iPad Pro screen with the Pencil, and later find the text, as you would if you had typed it. Is there an API so that developers can add this to their own apps?

Comment: https://martinmitrevski.com/2017/10/19/text-recognition-using-vision-and-coreml/

Comment: Maybe this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/handwriting_recognition

Answer (score 3):

There is no such API in iOS 11. But you could achieve this by using Vision Framework + CoreML. Vision can detect text rectangle and characters rectangles (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vntextobservation). After that you could pass images of each character to a trained CoreML model.